# How to use OptaPlanner

Tags: optaplanner

I am new to this thing and want to use Opta Planner in my project to Solve Vehicle Routing Problem. Can anyone guide me step by step how to use it, it would be great.

Thanks

Comment: [Read The Fabulous quick start Manual](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.1.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#quickStart)?

Comment: Please describe roughly your project ...

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet your fabulous quick start manual is useless, that's why there is a question here

Comment: @Ivanzinho please specify in detail what's missing, so we can fix it.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet I was just able to run the runExample.bat and see how it calculates the vehicle routing problem examples, I'm looking for documentation about how to use the VRPTW REST API but I wasn't able even to set up a server, I used Tomcat 8.5, Wildfly 10 but deploying the war file comes with lots of exceptions

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet how does one actually program optaplanner?  Are we supposed to edit the XML files?  Do you edit the .java files? Do you need to learn Drools?  It isn't really clear in the documentation exactly what you need to do.  There are many examples in the documentation with flow charts and diagrams, but it would be helpful to be more explicit about exactly what one needs to do and line by line explanations about what each line in the XML files and .java files are doing.

Comment: @Jeff Take a look at the Quick Start tutorial in the documentation. Using XML is optional (even for the solver config you can use the API approach instead).

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet Thanks -- I've been reading up on Drools and Java and went through the Quick Start; however, the Quick Start tutorial is very simple compared to the real life examples, such as nurse rostering, which have many, many subfolders and files.  Where do we begin if we want to modify these?  Is there a main file that loads all of them into a project of some sort? It would be great if there were detailed comments in these like the Quick Start. Is the .drl file the main file and all of the calls to the .java files come from here?

Comment: I am in the process of moving all optional files in examples to an optional package, so it's clearer what the "main" files are and which are just alterantive or advanced extra techniques. That being said, writing+maintaining a tutorial for every example separately is not in our team's current bandwidth. We are however working on something that will reduce the learning curve a lot, hopefully by the end of the year it will be ready.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet Glad to hear that you will try to reduce the learning curve. I really recommend that you flesh out each of the examples; specifically, in chapter 3 "Use Cases and Examples".  Review the relevant code and why each line is there.  It is very difficult to make the jump from the very brief description of  Nurse Rostering in section 3.1.5 which contains no code to all of the dozens of files stacked inside the examples folders in the files.  There are simply too many dots for new users to connect.  We aren't all optimization geniuses like you!

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet  For example, in the nurserostering example, in the shiftassignment.java file -- the code begins with: @ PlanningEntity(movableEntitySelectionFilter = MovableShiftAssignmentSelectionFilter.class,
        difficultyComparatorClass = ShiftAssignmentDifficultyComparator.class)
@ XStreamAlias("ShiftAssignment").  I understand you need PlanningEntity, but what is all the stuff inside the "()" for?  What is XStreamAlias for?  More comments in all of the code would be really helpful.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet It would also be helpful to consolidate all the files related to each example into one folder. Currently, you need to drill down a dozen levels to find files and they are scattered about many different subfolders. For example, the .drl file for nurserostering is here: "D:\optaplanner-distribution-7.9.0.Final\examples\sources\src\main\resources\org\optaplanner\examples\nurserostering\solver\"   but the java files are here:  "D:\optaplanner-distribution-7.9.0.Final\examples\sources\src\main\java\org\optaplanner\examples\nurserostering\domain" and even more files are elsewhere...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You make a good point about the complexity of the nurse rostering example's extra annotations. Not sure yet how to deal with those - as we do want to show some of those advanced features (such as custom movable filters etc) in some examples.

Answer (score 0):

In the current version (7.7) the docs have a quick start that explains the concepts on another use case and then see the VRP implementation example.

For a future version, we intend to make implementing/modeling VRP even simpler by supporting a `Vehicle.visitList` style model.